# Ошибка при проверке диска с помощью gdisk

Tags: linux, mbr, gpt

Система:
Процессор: Intel i7-3770
Материнка: Asus P8 H77-V
Видеокарта: Radeon 7950
HDD: WD Black 1TB
SSD(1): Plextor 128gb
SSD(2): Transcend 360S 128GB

У меня стоит Linux(2) и Windows(1) каждая ОС на своем SSD, загрузчик стоит на SSD(1). Сегодня после перезагрузки у меня перестал появлятться диалог с выбором загружаемой системы, после проверки SSD(1) получаю следующий вывод:

```
neon@neon:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Command (? for help): ?
b       back up GPT data to a file
c       change a partition's name
d       delete a partition
i       show detailed information on a partition
l       list known partition types
n       add a new partition
o       create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p       print the partition table
q       quit without saving changes
r       recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s       sort partitions
t       change a partition's type code
v       verify disk
w       write table to disk and exit
x       extra functionality (experts only)
?       print this menu

Command (? for help): v

Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.

Identified 1 problems!
```

---

Проверил SSD на битые секторы:

```
neon@neon:~$ sudo badblocks  -v /dev/sda > ~/test.list
Checking blocks 0 to 125034839
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):    
done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Эта ошибка говарит о том что повреджена таблица GPT или у нее какое то иное значение и можно ли востановить работу накопителя?

Если потребуется больше информации по вопросу готов ее предоставить.

Comment: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html - я так понимаю - надо сначала прожать `r`, а потом `b`. Ну и все остальные винты физически при этом лучше отрубить.

Comment: У тебя же на главной ссд не хранятся файлы в единственном экземпляре?

Comment: @don Rumata `r`-> `b` я уже пробовал, вывода никокого она не дала даже ошибки. На SSD у меня хранятся только проги которым нужна скорость и система.

Comment: Тогда пробуй дальше по списку.

Comment: @ don Rumata я не хочу эксперементировать с опциями которые мне не знакомы и потенциально опасны. Я бы хотел получить совет есть ли возможность востановления или я могу просто переставить винду.

Comment: Стоп. Я невнимательно прочитал. У тебя загрузчик в винде навернулся и он не может прочихаться. Так может лучше прогрузить винду с флэшки и восстановить загрузчик средствами винды?

Comment: @don Rumata а по сле этого можно будет grub записать на виндовый ssd для дуалбута?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63859/discussion-between-don-rumata-and-bleser).